# recursion c, program does not display

Tags: c, recursion

im facing an problem in this program, may anyone tell me, what im doing wrong, the program won't display anything after i give it input.
(Code is about sum of digits enter #example 12345 = 15)

```
#include<stdio.h>
int sum(int num);

int sum(int num){
int total=0;
if(sum==0){
    return total;
}
else{
    total+=num%10;
    num/=10;
    return sum(num);
}
}

int main()
{
int num,k;
printf("Enter 5 positive number: ");
scanf("%d",&num);
printf("Sum is: %d",sum(num));
}
```

Comment: Your `total` is initialized to `0` for every call.

Comment: Right, thanks but still does not display its stuck on cursor symbol

Comment: Write the recursive rule first. On paper.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to change the condition from `sum==0` to `num==0`. It will now print something. However, the logic of your program is still wrong. You can change your sum function to this.

```
int sum(int num){
    if(num==0) {
        return 0;
    }
    return num % 10 + sum(num/10);
}
```

And you can try learning more about recursion through stack since recursion is basically just stack.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a rule of thumb, whenever you have a non-stopping recursion program try to verify your base cases.

Here you are verifying `sum` the function instead of `num` the parameter. The C compiler let's you do that because functions in C are pointers, and pointers hold the addresses as numeric value.

Comment: oh mann, thank you so much, what an idiot i am.

Answer (score 0):

In your code the total gets initialized to zero every time the function is called. and a variable named sum is not initialized. Just change sum==0 to num==0.I have also given the logic to sum the digits of a number.

[image]